# Is there Telerik UI for UWP nuget for UNO?

Tags: nuget, uno-platform

https://github.com/unoplatform/Uno.Telerik.UI-For-UWP is there a nuget for this repo?
I couldn't find any on nuget and Telerik.UI.for.UniversalWindowsPlatform is not support on mobile projects. Thanks.

Comment: I would suggest to contact with the owner of this fork.

Comment: I already ask him in discord. he direct me to ask here so the other can benefit from the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[Update 2]**
I am no longer continuing development on this and instead focusing my efforts on [Telerik UI for MAUI](https://www.telerik.com/maui-ui).

**[Update]**

I am working on making this available for the Uno community. You can find it on nuget.org at `xxx`

**[Original]**

Telerik doesn't own that fork, so they do not publish a NuGet package for it.

If you would like to have a NuGet package, you can clone the repo locally and compile it yourself. See the [Getting Started](https://github.com/unoplatform/Uno.Telerik.UI-For-UWP#getting-started) section of the README to lean how to compile the repository.

#### Generate NuGet Package

Once it is compiled, you can generate a `.nupkg` file (see number 6):

1. Make sure you have the required software to build UWP applications
2. Clone a copy of the repository code
3. Open UWPControls.sln located in Controls folder and build it
4. Open UWPMap.sln located in Controls folder and build it in x86/x64 and ARM configs
5. All binaries are now located in Binaries folder
6. You can additionally build a NuGet package by running `BuildTools/BuildNuGet.bat`. The generated package will be located in the NuGet subfolder.

#### Next Steps

Once you have your own nupkg file, you can put it in a Package Source (i.e. just a local folder) or put it in your own nuget feed server and list that as a packages source.